# Modifying Columns in R Studio

Tags: dataset, rstudio

I have a sensor data in R studio. Each of the column values have semi colon in the end. 
What should I write to remove the semicolons from each value. I am attaching a picture.
This data set is quite big, like about 5300 about entries.
I want to remove semicolons, so I can easily plot them using ggplot()
[Sensor Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Kp3E.jpg)

This is my code:

library(ggplot2)
T <- Sensor$V3

Displacement1 <- Sensor$V4

ggplot(Sensor, aes(x =T, y = Displacement1)) + geom_point()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have recreated the Sensor dataset as a simplified CSV file (I called "iStack2.csv") which reads

[image]

Than you need to work on that file, clean it up and replace things to get a data frame like that

```
    ID      T Displacement1
1 0002 18.628       -0.0345
2 0003  17.28       -0.0245
3 0004 18.328       -0.0145
4 0005 19.628       -0.1245
5 0006  1.628        -0.345
6 0007 28.628       -0.2345
```

Here is the entire code with ggplot

```
rm(list=ls())
library(ggplot2) 

filenames <- "iStack2.csv"

delim = ","
DF <- read.csv(filenames,header = F,sep=delim)
print(DF)
print(is.data.frame(DF))

DF2 <- data.frame(lapply(DF, function(x) gsub("13:00:", "", x)))
DF3 <- data.frame(lapply(DF2, function(x) gsub("=", "", x)))
DF4 <- data.frame(lapply(DF3, function(x) gsub(";", "", x)))
colnames(DF4) <- c("ID","T","Displacement1")


p1 <- ggplot(DF4, aes(x=T, y=Displacement1)) +
  geom_point()

print(p1)
```

the plot you get 
[image]

Hope this helps, obviously if would be better if you could produce a clean dataset to start with, it would save you lots of time.